# Why am i getting InvalidValueError: in property origin: must set one of location, placeId or query error in angular?

Tags: angular, agm-direction

In my `angular10` app i am using `agm core` to show `google maps`.

component.html

```
<agm-map [latitude]="latitude" [longitude]="longitude">
  <agm-direction *ngIf="source && dest"  [origin]="source" [destination]="dest"></agm-direction>
</agm-map>
```

component.ts

```
ngOnInit(){
 // above code...
 this.source = {
   lat: +(this.bidlocation.pickup.lat),
   lng: +(this.bidlocation.pickup.long)
 };
 this.dest = {
   lat: +(this.bidlocation.dropOff.lat),
   lng: +(this.bidlocation.dropOff.long)
 }
}
```

Now `map` is showing and `direction` is also showing on `map` correctly but i am getting this `error` on `console`

```
InvalidValueError: in property origin: must set one of location, placeId or query
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to use  source: any ; without any {} obj mapping
This one solve my problem